# Is there any successful Windows Azure based website and web services?

Tags: google-app-engine, azure

I am evaluating Windows Azure and Google App Engine.

Personally I prefer Windows Azure as I have been a C# developer for years. However, I do understand Azure will be too expensive for a start up company.

Could anyone let me know any successful Azure based website or web services?

Any opinion about Azure VS GAE is welcome.

Thanks

Comment: Kevin: without understanding more of your specific requirements in terms of site traffic, kind of storage, your skills in development, and the nature of the site -- this will be a hard topic for anyone here to answer. Do feel free to post another question that's more detailed.

Comment: "Any opinion about X vs. Y" is way too general. Please make your questions more specific.

Comment: A startup can use Azure for free with BizSpark, so probably less expensive than GAE's new pricing schedule.

Comment: Thanks for your replies. I am not going to make websites on those platforms. I am going to write web services. My feeling is that Azure will charge me even if my web service traffic is zero. But there is no cost for GAE.

Comment: Unless you're using the free/restricted GAE offering, you will still be billed by Google even if you have zero traffic because you'll still be paying for a compute instance to listen for traffic. This is kinda the industry norm which is fair enough. Also note that for every cloud option ive looked at, their SLA's require at least 2 instance of a compute instance. So if one falls over the other can take over while the trashed instance is brought down and restarted so note when GAE offers a free service it's only for 28 hrs. So you couldn't run 2 instances for that all day. i.e. 24 * = 48 not 28

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google can give you the answer to who is using Azure and how they are using it. 
Whatever answer is given today will not neccessarily be accurate when this post is read so it's a bit of a time lock. Boeing is using Azure. Microsoft is using Azure. Azure is even using Azure.

I disagree that Azure is anymore expensive than any other PaaS offering.
And I find Azure as a PaaS offering to be "bizarrely" less expensive than IaaS offering from the likes of Rackspace etc.

I say "bizarrely" because we get the hardware and the platform for less than what Rackspace charge us for just the hardware. I find it's very reasonably priced so long as you read the not so fine print....

***i.e. watch out for part hour charging and know that deployed = paying whether the service is turned on or not.***

I've found GAE to be similar in cost. Which metric are you particularly interested in?

I also dont agree that it's too expensive for a startup. 
I can get a 2 small instance with a 1 Gb database and CDN use for about $130NZD a month. 
That's peanuts when you look at the amount of grunt sitting in behind that... specially when you consider you can run multiple domains off a single hosted service.

Azure vs GAE is IHMO really just a developmental/deployment difference in the stack.
I'm an MS developer and I can ride my skillset into Azure very easily.

There's so much info and so many introductory videos available on it's use. Check out the latest build conference videos and a series called [Cloud Cover](http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Cloud+Cover) on channel 9).

You can get up and running on Azure in a basic developer test sense in half a day to a day. It's a really very well thought out offering IMHO.

So there you go, a very general answer to a very general question. ;-)

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your reply. I have been a Windows developer and Java developer. But personally I prefer C# lot than Java. I would choose Azure with no doubt if it offers a free quota like GAE. My other question is that: Do I need to start paying for Azure even at the testing stage of my application?

Comment: Hi Kevin,No you can sign up for 90 days of Azure for free, subject to some instance size constraints etc. You will need a credit card and you will need to terminate the account before 90 days if you dont want actual  billing to be triggered. Beyond development it's a great way to see what you might be up for re: costs once/if you transfer to paid subscription. Even if you're not load testing it still helped me to better understand all the bits you get billed for. Initially it seems like you're getting slammed with charges but upon reflection it's actually quite fair and reasonable.